# How can I change components of a form from within another object?

Tags: c#

I got an object, which is called in my form1-window. How can I change anything from the form1-object from within this object, for example a label or a processbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be a bad (circular) design to give your object a reference to your form. Use an interface or a delegate (callback).

```
// untested code
class MyObjectClass
{
   public delegate void Reportback(int percentage);

   public void DoSomething(Reportback callBack) { ...; callback(i*100F/total); ...}
}


class Form1: Form
{
   private void reportProgress(int percent) { ...; progressbar1.value = percent; }

   void SomeMethod() {  myObject1.DoSomething(reportprogress); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you find yourself with a need for one object to manipulate the private fields of another, your design needs work.

For instance, an class that's performing some kind of long-running business logic shouldn't be updating a `ProgressBar`.  First, that's not its job.  Second, that couples the functioning of the business logic to the implementation details of the user interface.

It's much better if the class simply raises events as it performs its long-running task.  For instance, look at this class:

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    public event EventHandler ProgressChanged;

    private int _Progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _Progress;  }
        private set
        {
            _Progress = value;
            EventHandler h = ProgressChanged;
            if (h != null)
            {
                h(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever any method in this class sets the `Progress` property, the `ProgressChanged` event gets raised.  In your form, you can instantiate the object with logic like this:

```
private BusinessLogic Task;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task = new BusinessLogic();
    Task.ProgressChanged += Task_ProgressChanged;
}

void Task_ProgressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    taskProgessBar.Value = ((BusinessLogic) sender).Progress;
}
```

Now, every time a method in the `Task` object sets the `Progress` property, the `ProgressBar` in the form will get updated.

This is quite a bit more code to write than just having the object update the `ProgressBar`, sure.  But look what you get out of it.  If you have to refactor your form into two forms, and move the task to a new form, you don't have to touch the `BusinessLogic` class.  If you move your `ProgressBar` from being a control on the form to being a `ToolStripProgressBar` on a `ToolStrip`, you don't have to touch the `BusinessLogic` class.  If you decide that progress reporting isn't important, you don't have to touch the `BusinessLogic` class.

Essentially, this approach protects the `BusinessLogic` class from having to know *anything* about the user interface.  This makes it a lot easier to change both the business logic and the user interface as your program evolves.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Henk... but anyway, you can modify any item on a form if you change the visibility of the controls, there is even a property for doing this.

Comment: By visibility, are you talking about scope (Private, Protected, Public?)

Comment: Yes. If you change it to public or internal, you can access it. I use that approach in a Project, but it's messy, so I'll refactor using Henks solution today.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say. Making form controls themselves Public is a terrible ideal. Worst case should be making a Public function in form code that sets the Private/Protected form controls.